# How to make a rope in libGDX box2D more springy?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I created few `Box2D` rope joints in `libGDX`. The ropes feel a bit too floppy. How can you make the ropes more stiff? The main `Box2D project` shows an option for stiffness in their testbed demo:
[image]
The rope on the right side shows the desired stiffness:
[image]

Does such option exist in `libGDX Box2D`?

Thats how I create my ropes in `libGDX`:

```
private void initRopeJoints() {
    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
    bodies.add(BodyBuilder.createBox(world,250,360,32,32,true,true));
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
        bodies.add(BodyBuilder.createBox(world, 250, -i * 32 +300, 4, 32, false, false));
        RopeJointDef rDef = new RopeJointDef();
        rDef.bodyA = bodies.get(i - 1);
        rDef.bodyB = bodies.get(i);
        rDef.collideConnected = true;
        rDef.maxLength = 1f; // meters because box2d works in meters
        rDef.localAnchorA.set(0, -0.5f);
        rDef.localAnchorB.set(0, .5f);
        world.createJoint(rDef);
    }
}

// makes stronger rope - e.g. will not break
private void initRopeJointsSecondApproach() {
    Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
    bodies.add(BodyBuilder.createBox(world,250,60 +270,32,4,true,true));
    for(int i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        bodies.add(BodyBuilder.createBox(world, 250, -i * 4 +270, 4, 4, false, false));
        RopeJointDef rDef = new RopeJointDef();
        rDef.bodyA = bodies.get(0);
        rDef.bodyB = bodies.get(i);
        rDef.collideConnected = true;
        rDef.maxLength = i * .25f;
        rDef.localAnchorA.set(0, -.125f);
        rDef.localAnchorB.set(0, .125f);

        world.createJoint(rDef);

        RevoluteJointDef jDef = new RevoluteJointDef();
        jDef.bodyA = bodies.get(i - 1);
        jDef.bodyB = bodies.get(i);
        jDef.localAnchorA.set(0, -.125f);
        jDef.localAnchorB.set(0, .125f);

        world.createJoint(jDef);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I get it. The joints (RopeJoint/RevoluteJoint) will not provide you with the desired effect, since they do not restrict the rotation of bodies around each other. Use WeldJoint with adjusted parameters frequency and damping ratio.

setDampingRatio(float ratio);
setFrequency(float hz);

It is difficult to say which parameters of frequency and damping ratio you need. Change them until the flexibility you need is achieved.

Comment: Awesome! That worked really well with WeldJoints. The "rope" is now springy enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you do not like that your rope behaves like rubber or a spring. This has to do with how box2d constraint solver works. For each connection it tries to correct the position of the bodies. Overall, it works out well. But when there are many of connections, it takes time for the solver to put the bodies in correct positions. For this reason, the spring effect arises. To decrease it, you can decrease the simulation time step. This will make the behavior of the connections more accurate, but will increase the CPU utilization. But in your case, it would be best to add another RopeJoint, which would connect the first and the last body of your rope and have a length equal to the length of the rope. This connection will prevent the beginning and end of the rope from moving further than the length of your rope.

Comment: My goal is to have a more springy and less floppy rope. I added a gif which shows the desired behaviour. I also realised the previous screenshot highlighted the wrong stiffness field. Sry, I meant the bend model (and not stretch model).